# Selenium hangs instantiating FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I try to get started with selenium (downloaded the current version today) and copied their example which opens a browser and performs a google search.

However, the program hangs forever in the 1st line `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`.

I have Firefox 13 installed.

```
Thread dump:
Thread [main]
  Thread.sleep(long) line: not available [native method] [local variables unavailable]
  FirefoxBinary.sleep(long) line: 218
  FirefoxBinary.clean(FirefoxProfile, File) line: 234
  NewProfileExtensionConnection.start() line: 76
  FirefoxDriver.startClient() line: 200
  FirefoxDriver(RemoteWebDriver).(CommandExecutor, Capabilities) line: 94
  FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxBinary, FirefoxProfile) line: 147
  FirefoxDriver.() line: 85
  Test.main(String[]) line: 24
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These cases are usually when Firefox & Selenium are a little "out of sync" in terms of compatibility.

You should try two things: update Selenium to the latest one and/or downgrade Firefox. Keeping an eye on the [Selenium Release Notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609557/where-to-find-selenium-webdriver-release-notes)

Comment: Right, Selenium hasn't released support for Firefox 13 yet.

Comment: Selenium 2.23 includes Firefox 13 support.

Comment: My answer was before Firefox 13 even reached release stages, I've edited it to now.

Comment: There is also a pageLoadTimeout now.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 13 support was added in Selenium 2.23. See http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: +1 Thanks. That did it for me. Updated Selenium via Package Manager. Bang! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a new browser's hot - I was looking for a problem elsewhere. Webdriver or selenium server. http://d.pr/i/Q5Dt

Answer (score 0):

I've been working OK with Firefox 18, but I just got auto-updated to 19 which seems to break the webdriver. Mozilla isn't prominent with the links to prior versions:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/18.0b7/mac/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

Saw this behavior when trying to instantiate the webdriver on a headless CentOS server **without display being set**.

Per https://serverfault.com/questions/363827/how-can-i-run-firefox-on-centos-with-no-display -- you can use **Xvfb**, which gives you an X server that doesn't require connection to a physical display

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.