# Exiting a program after a certain amount of time - Java

Tags: java, selenium, exit

I am writing a program in Selenium using Java. In my code, I have:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

My problem is this: if I am not connected to the internet when the program executes this line of code, the program will hang for a long time (on the order of minutes) before finally opening up a Firefox Window and then crashing on the next line of code

```
driver.doWhatever();
```

I am trying to make this as user friendly as possible, so I would love to have my program exit if

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

does not complete within fifteen to twenty seconds.

Is there a way to do this in Java? I could always go into Selenium and tinker with it so that it works the way I want it to, but that seems like the "wrong" way to go about solving this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Downgrading Firefox (or upgrading Selenium) Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715576/selenium-hangs-instantiating-firefoxdriver?

Comment: I could try this, but Selenium seems to be working normally 99% of the time. It is only when I am not connected to the internet that it hangs, and then only for a while. To me, it seems like "hanging while offline" is perfectly normal behavior, I'm just looking for a way to change that behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver class may be modified to adjust the wait time that you are having trouble with.

It should look something like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You could adjust the time to whatever you want, but be warned that reducing it too low may cause other issues, for example if the page is simply taking a little longer to load, it will timeout prematurely.

Source: [WebDriver: Advanced Usage -- Selenium Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: Great! This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for. It solves my problem and does not require actually messing with the Selenium source. I figured that there was a solution for me out there somewhere.