# Where to find Selenium Webdriver release notes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for a release notes for Selenium WebDriver which gives details what are new features, what are bugs etc in the release.

I could find for Selenium IDE [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes) But couldn't find for Selenium Webdriver. If anybody knows, please point me to the link.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They live in the source control for the project under the respective folder for the particular language libraries. That means:

1. .NET Libraries: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG
2. Java Libraries: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG
3. Python Libraries: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/CHANGES
4. Ruby libraries: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/CHANGES
5. NodeJS libraries: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md

'Special' ones:

1. IEDriverServer changelog: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG

Comment: @Arran Is there a changelog for Selenium Server? Couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Javascript (Node) Changelog: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 8):

1. visit http://docs.seleniumhq.org/
2. Click 'Download' tab.
3. Scroll down to section 'Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings'
4. 'Change log' link for each languages.

Answer (score 2):

## Release Notes (Change_Log)

---

> ## JAVA
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG
>
> ## Python
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/CHANGES
>
> ## C#
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG
>
> ## Ruby
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/CHANGES
>
> ## JavaScript (Node)
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md
>
> ## IEDriverserver
>
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG
>   http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG

## 3rd Party Browser Drivers [NOT Developed by seleniumhq]

---

> ## ChromeDriver
>
> http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.7/notes.txt
>   http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt
>
> ## OperaDriver
>
> https://raw.github.com/operasoftware/operadriver/master/CHANGES
>
> ## GhostDriver (PhantomJS)
>
> https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md